# Unexpected token '(' error batch apex

Tags: apex, soql, batch, dynamic-soql, querylocator

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{
    String query = 'select id,ParticipantName__c,EpisodePoPEndDate__c from BPCIAe__c where id in :CHildParentMap.keyset() OR id in :ParentWithdrawaldateMap.keyset()  and (EpisodePoPEndDate__c=null OR PoPEndDate__c > TODAY)';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

Unexpected token ( is thrown at the  Database.Querylocator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use any sort of dot reference in a dynamic bind variable. So anywhere you are calling `.keySet()`, you would need to cache that `Set` to be referenced directly.

**Invalid**

```
String query = '...WHERE Id IN CHildParentMap.keyset() OR Id IN :ParentWithdrawaldateMap.keyset()'
```

**Valid**

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
ids.addAll(childParentMap.keySet());
ids.addAll(parentWithdrawalDateMap.keySet());
String query = '...WHERE Id IN :ids'
```

A side benefit in this case is it allows you to eliminate an `OR` clause, which is always a win.

---

For your reference:

> ## [Dynamic SOQL Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm)
>
> You can use simple bind variables in dynamic SOQL query strings. The following is allowed:
>
> ```
> String myTestString = 'TestName';
> List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myTestString');
> ```
>
> However, unlike inline SOQL, dynamic SOQL can’t use bind variable fields in the query string. The following example isn’t supported and results in a Variable does not exist error:
>
> ```
> MyCustomObject__c myVariable = new MyCustomObject__c(field1__c ='TestField');
> List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE field1__c = :myVariable.field1__c');
> ```
>
> You can instead resolve the variable field into a string and use the string in your dynamic SOQL query:
>
> ```
> String resolvedField1 = myVariable.field1__c;
> List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE field1__c = ' + resolvedField1);
> ```